# (REDDIT) Error trying to subscribe to subreddits via API

Tags: ruby, reddit

I know that [Snoo](https://github.com/paradox460/snoo) seems to be unmaintained, but I wanted to use a ruby framework since I'm trying to improve my Ruby skill.

I'm trying to add some functionality starting with subscribing and unsubscribing to subreddits. [Link to API doc.](http://www.reddit.com/dev/api#POST_api_subscribe)

My first attempt was with the built-in post method which returned a 404 error

```
def subscribe(subreddit)
    logged_in?
    post('/api/subscribe.json',body:{uh: @modhash, action:'sub', sr: subreddit, api_type: 'json'})
end
```

Since the built-in post method was giving me a 404 I decided to try the HTTParty post method:

```
def subscribe(subreddit)
    logged_in?
    HTTParty.post('http://www.reddit.com/api/subscribe.json',body:{uh: @modhash, action:'sub', sr: subreddit, api_type: 'json'})
end
```

That returns this:

```
pry(main)> reddit.subscribe('/r/nba')
=> {"json"=>{"errors"=>[["USER_REQUIRED", "please login to do that", nil]]}}
```

Does anyone know if I need to pass more info in the body or if I'm just sending a badly formed request? Thanks!

Also, before running "reddit.subscribe" I have verified that I'm logged in with with a cookie, a modhash, can access my account info, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Solution found:

```
def subscribe(subreddit)
  #query the subreddit for it's 'about' info and get json back
  subreddit_json = self.subreddit_info(subreddit)

  #build the coded unique identifier for the targeted subreddit
  subreddit_id = subreddit_json['kind'] + "_" + subreddit_json['data']['id']

  #send post request to server
  server_response = self.class.post('/api/subscribe.json',
    body:{uh:@modhash, action:'sub', sr: subreddit_id, api_type:'json'})
end
```

The Reddit API doesn't accept the subreddit name as the value passed with 'sr', (e.g. sr:'/r/funny'). It requires the subreddit "type" (which is always 't5' for subreddits) and unique forum id. The parameter passed would look something like: sr: "t5_2qo4s". This information is available if you go to your target subreddit and add about.json, e.g., www.reddit.com/r/funny/about.json